# How can I append additional fields to each line in a CSV file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, scripting

This is not a question about appending a new line of text to a file; it's about appending data to each row.

I have over 300 lines in a CSV file, and I want to add more text to each line separated with commas (a format used for MS Excel charts).

From the *ex.txt* file:

```
12:11, 321
12:12, 23
```

I want to append more fields to each line, like this:

```
12:11, 321, 222, 55
12:12, 23, 33, 402
```

Comment: And from where are those extra fields coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 while read line; do
     # modify $whatYouWantToAppend
     echo -e "${line} ${whatYouWantToAppend}\n" >> newTest.txt
 done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Use Paste from GNU CoreUtils

Assuming that you aren't appending a static string, your issue is that you need to read text from one file and append text from another file. That's exactly what the [paste](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html) command does.

#### Sample Files

Contents of file1:

```
12:11, 321
12:12, 23
```

Contents of file2:

```
 222, 55
 33, 402
```

Note the leading spaces in the first column of file2. This is needed to preserve your described format, which seems to be CSV with leading spaces after each delimiter.

#### Sample Invocation and Output

```
$ paste -d, file1 file2
12:11, 321, 222, 55
12:12, 23, 33, 402
```